# Download Apple hosted on-demand tagged resources via Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, on-demand-resources

I'm digging around Apple documentation about [on-demand resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/IntrotoHostingODR.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015083-CH17-SW1) but I can't find this information..

Is it possible to fetch On-Demand Resources (eg. image, Javascript bundle) from a WKWebView via Javascript?

My intent is to publish some (big) HTML+JS games on Apple servers as On-Demand tagged Resources and then fetch them via Javascript XHR calls or through a Cordova/Phonegap/Ionic plugin.

In this way:

1. We would not affect the App final bundle size including all the games
2. Apple would be able to review the games (since it's not externally "injected code" - that is against their guidelines).

---

In my specific case, I would use the Cordova plugin [cordova-plugin-filetransfer](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer) to download the tagged on-demand resources and [cordova-plugin-file](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/) to load and display the downloaded game into the webview.

---

This is what we need to achieve due to business constraints. Is it feasible?

Comment: Hello, have you got any progress or updates on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It looks like it is possible to download a zip file, uncompress it and load it into the Cordova webview using a Cordova only solution (using [cordova-plugin-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file)).
2. Apple only lets you access those On-Demand Resources using their Native API, they don't have exposed those via an external API.

So, in order to load ODRs in a Cordova App, we would need to create a custom plugin that calls the Native API that takes care of loading the On-Demand Resources (see [NSBundleResourceRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundleresourcerequest)).

Reply found in the Reddit Flutter community:

https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/ejmf3a/apples_odr_network_via_flutter/

[image]

Comment: Add the same time there is an open PR that would allow you to use a command to add those tags through Cordova: https://github.com/apache/cordova-node-xcode/pull/87. But if that's the case how can we then load them through Cordova, as there does not seem to be a Cordova plugin out there that does it for us?

Comment: (update here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61094404/able-to-read-downloaded-on-demand-resource-in-ios-simulator-but-not-on-physical)

Comment: have you sorted this? I am working at the moment on a cordova app and need the apple's odr?

Comment: ok I've sorted this one as well, by doing a custom plugin